# Ordering of positive and negative terms in output

Tags: output-formatting

Consider the following input and output:

In:

> Solve[(1 - a) x == (2 - a) y, x]

Out: $$\left\{\left\{x\rightarrow\frac{(-2+a)y}{-1+a}\right\}\right\}$$

---

There are two things I don't like about this output (the first fairly generic, and the second more specific to my application):

1. the fact that the negative term is written first makes the expression less compact than the alternative:$$\frac{(a-2)y}{a-1}.$$
   I find this alternative to be typographically neater.
2. If $a$ is a probability, it is guaranteed to be no greater than 1. I think it makes semantically more sense to write the output as $$\frac{(2-a)y}{1-a}.$$ Obviously, Mathematica doesn't know that $0\leq a\leq 1$, but I supplied the terms written as $2-a$ rather than $a-2$ and it would be nice if it were to preserve this ordering to some extent.

---

Thus, my questions are

1. Why does mathematica write $-2+a$ in the solution rather than $a-2$?
2. Is there a way to get mathematica to arrange output so that terms start with a leading "$-$" as rarely as possible?
3. If there a way to tell Mathematica "$a\in[\underline{a},\overline{a}]$; please use this information, where possible, to arrange output such that terms are written as (positive x positive) rather than (negative x negative)?"

Comment: *Mathematica* has a canonical ordering behind the scenes. Since `Plus` is `Orderless`, `Plus[a, -2]` will always become `Plus[-2, a`], because numbers come before symbols in the canonical ordering. Furthermore, when *Mathematica* simplifies, it's figure of merit for simplifying includes `LeafCount`, which is a proxy for the complexity of the expression, and `((-2 + a) y)/(-1 + a)` has a smaller `LeafCount` than `((2 - a) y)/(1 - a)`. Now, there are ways to display this more nicely, if all you care about is displaying. Maybe I'll search for an example Q&A that answers your question.

Comment: `TraditionalForm` will do what you want, but take care to only use it for display purpose, eg do `TraditionalForm[solution = Solve[(1 - a) x == (2 - a) y, x]]` so that `solution` holds the unformatted expression.

Comment: @march : I'm not sure if this is due to Plus being Orderless, since if you evaluate `ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]`,   `a - 2` still becomes `-2 + a`.  Also, I'm not sure if it's due to LeafCount either, since `a - 2` and `-2 + a` both have a LeafCount of 3.

Comment: @george2079 : As I understand it, this is a concern if do what you illustrated (applying TraditionalForm to an input) (and is also a concern if you copy-and-paste TraditionalForm output into a new input), but is not an issue if you globally set output to TraditionalForm in Preferences -> Evaluation.  For more information, see "tutorial/HowInputAndOutputWork" in MMA's help documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default order of terms is determined based on lexicographic sorting rules that can in principle be exploited to get the output in just the right form:

```
Solve[(\[FormalX] - a) x == (\[FormalY] - a) y, x] /. 
    {\[FormalX] -> 1, \[FormalY] -> 2}
```

[image: output]

Here, I used the fact that the formal symbols come before the alphabet symbols, i.e., `Ordering[{\[FormalX],a}]` gives `{1, 2}`. This causes the output of `Solve` to have the desired order when using the formal symbols instead of numerical values. The latter are then substituted only after `Solve` has produced a formal result.