# Separate or order the positive and negative terms of an expression

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation

I am using Mathematica to manipulate/keep track of a long series of symbol manipulations.

One thing that I would like to do is separate or order the terms of an expression by positive and negative sign.

For example separating 
[image]
or something more simple that we can use as an example

```
b+ c^2 -c^2 +a^4 -c^5
```

I say  order by positive or negative sign as (for my problem) we assume that the constants are all positive.

I looked at [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127333/ordering-of-positive-and-negative-terms-in-output) but I don't know how I can apply this to my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Values @ GroupBy[
    List @@ (b+c^2-c^2+a^4-c^5),
    Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ,
    Total
]
```

> {a^4 + b, -c^5}

**Addendum**

OP requested a function:

```
posneg[expr_] := Values @ GroupBy[
    Replace[expr,
        {
        a_Plus :> List@@a,
        a_ :> {a}
        }
    ],
    Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ,
    Total
]
```

A couple examples:

```
posneg[b+c^2-c^3+a^4-c^5]
posneg[x-2]
```

> {a^4 + b + c^2, -c^3 - c^5}
>
> {-2, x}

**Update**

A comment requested a version that always returns both the negative and positive parts, padding with 0 if necessary.

One way to do this is to add both a positive and a negative number to the list, and then remove those numbers at the end. Here is a variation that does this:

```
posneg[expr_]:=Values@GroupBy[
    Replace[expr,
        {
        a_Plus:>Join[{-1,1}, List@@a],
        a_:>{-1, 1, a}
        }
    ],
    Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ,
    Total @* Rest
]
```

Examples:

```
posneg[-x]
posneg[x]
```

> {-x, 0}
>
> {0, x}

Comment: Looks great. Can it be written so that it can be defined once and used as a function.

Comment: Did you want `List @@ expr` instead of `List @@ Flatten[{expr}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I wanted the function to work for both `Plus` and non-`Plus` objects. Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks just what I was looking for.

Comment: I have found this thread by searching and found this routine really useful. Is there a way to modify it though so that it always returns a two-element list? For now, posneg[x] and posneg[-x] give me one-element lists {x} and {-x}, whereas I would prefer {x,0} and {0,-x} so that I can use First[posneg[p]] and Last[posneg[p]] uniformly as positive and negative parts of some polynomial p.

Comment: @Balazs Please see update.

Answer (score 6):

perhaps

```
ClearAll[order]
order[Times[x_?Negative, _]| _?Negative] := -1
order[_] := 1;

GatherBy[List@@(b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5), order]
```

> {{a^6, b, c^2}, {-c^3, -c^5}}

```
Values @ GroupBy[List @@ (b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5), order]
```

> {{a^6, b, c^2}, {-c^3, -c^5}}

```
Values @ GroupBy[List @@ (b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5), order, Total]
```

> {a^6 + b + c^2, -c^3 - c^5}

```
Values @ Merge[Identity][order[#] -> # & /@ (List @@ (b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5))]
```

> {{a^6, b, c^2}, {-c^3, -c^5}}

```
Values @ Merge[Total][order[#] -> # & /@ (List @@ (b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5))]
```

> {a^6 + b + c^2, -c^3 - c^5}

```
SortBy[Inactivate[b + c^2 - c^3 + a^6 - c^5, Plus], order]
```

> -c^3 + -c^5 + a^6 + b + c^2

Comment: Can you tell me what the second thing does?

Comment: It groups the elements of the set according to the condition `order`, as previously defined.

Comment: Thank you @David.  AzJ, wrapped it with `Values` now to get a list of groups rather than an `Association`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

Definitions:

```
sum = b + c^2 - c^2 + a^4 - c^5;

signList = List[];

posList = List[];

negList = List[];
```

Function to find the sign of the term by dividing the term by the absolute value of the term, in the list on the end you can put the assumptions on the constants.

```
sign[i_, expr_] := 
 Refine[expr[[i]]/Abs[expr[[i]]], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

Make a list where you find all the signs. For-loop going through all the terms, using the fn sign to find the sign and put it in signList.

```
findOrder[expr_] := For[i = 1, i < (Length[expr] + 1), i++, signList = Append[signList, N[sign[i, expr]]]]
```

Then order the terms in two separate lists, depending on their sign.

```
orderTerms[expr_] := For[i = 1, i < (Length[expr] + 1), i++, If[signList[[i]] > 0, posList = Append[posList, expr[[i]]], negList = Append[negList, expr[[i]]]]]
```

So for this example:

```
findOrder[sum]

orderTerms[sum]

posList
```

> {a^4, b}

```
negList
```

> {-c^5}

Is this what you wanted?